# How to set up Android Emulator behind Proxy using custom certification

Tags: android, authentication, proxy, certificate, emulation

I need to access the internet from the Android Emulator behind a corporate proxy... I set it up with login credentials in the Emulator config, also install the certificate issueb by my company, but for the love of god, it only works in Chrome, not in any other browser i have tried nor my application that i develop can access the internet.

Please help...

[here is a video describing the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUK6Ne9bdCM)

Comment: The proxy support in the emulator is so buggy that after every update you have to search for a new reliably working solution. Currently, 2018/09/13 NOTHING works.